How to Command prompt while making a python.exe file for Tkinter
How to hide Command Prompt for a exe file in tkinter, Why? I need to make an application for easy converting for farenheit to celsius and vice versa, I dont want bloatware, thats why. Please help
Code:
`
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def convert_temperature():
temp = entry.get()
try:
temp = float(temp)
if var.get() == "Celsius":
fahrenheit = temp \* (9/5) + 32
result_label.config(text=f"{temp}°C is {fahrenheit:.2f}°F")
elif var.get() == "Fahrenheit":`your text`
celsius = (temp - 32) \* (5/9)
result_label.config(text=f"{temp}°F is {celsius:.2f}°C")
except ValueError:
messagebox.showerror("Invalid input", "Please enter a valid number")

# Create the main window

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Temperature Converter")

# Create a label and entry for temperature input

entry_label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter temperature:")
entry_label.pack()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

# Create radio buttons for Celsius and Fahrenheit

var = tk.StringVar(value="Celsius")
celsius_radio = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Celsius", variable=var, value="Celsius")
celsius_radio.pack()
fahrenheit_radio = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="Fahrenheit", variable=var, value="Fahrenheit")
fahrenheit_radio.pack()

# Create a button to trigger the conversion

convert_button = tk.Button(root, text="Convert", command=convert_temperature)
convert_button.pack()

#Create a label to display the result
result_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
result_label.pack()

#Run the application
root.mainloop()

#Command Prompt Opens, I want it to not open

What are you using to create an .exe?

Try changing the file extension to .pyw.

If you're using pyinstaller to create an executable, you can pass the option -w, --windowed or --noconsole. If the file you're converting has the extension .pyw (like @acw1668 suggested) then this option is set implicitly.

I guess that you are working on Windows, as you talk about python.exe. When you install Python on Windows, the installer registers 2 file extensions: .py and .pyw

Double clicking on a .py file, launches the IDE (either IDLE or another IDE that you may have installed)
Double clicking on a .pyw file, launches the python engine to run the code, without the shell window (cmd.exe on Windows)

As your code creates a standalone window with tkinter, simply rename your file as filename.pyw, and then double clicking the file in Explorer will launch your app, without the shell window
But this is only working when the python IDE is installed on the user computer. So if you want to share your code with friends that don't have Python on their computer, you have to create a true Windows executable file for your app, using tools such as pyinstaller. As recalled by JRiggles above, when applying pyinstaller on a .pyw file, it automatically applies the flag --noconsole which means 'no shell window' on execution.
